# how to parse new Date object to dd mm yy 09-07-2020 before 30 days its answer is provided by me

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, .net, bootstrap-4

> this is for all who are finding solution for getting jquery date before 30 days in format dd-mm-yy
>  `var today = new Date()`
> `var priorDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() +30)` this will give days before 30 days in format  11422252525262
>  `var strdate = new Date(priorDate)` this will turn it into jan 5 2020 9.30 pm
> `var date1 = strdate.toLocaleDateString()` this will give convert date to eg: 09/08/2020

Comment: is this a question?

Comment: godzilla just got a stroke trying to read this ;) Please format your question so it gets understandable.

Comment: no this is answer for a specific format

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var today = new Date()
var priorDate = new Date().setDate(today.getDate() +30)
```

- That will give any days before 30 days in this format: `11422252525262`

```
var strdate = new Date(priorDate)
```

- will turn it into jan 5 2020 9.30 pm.

```
var date1 = strdate.toLocaleDateString()
```

- will convert the date to eg: 09/08/2020

Answer (score 0):

When ever any Date related functionlities are to be implemented in .net make sure to import the namespace "using System".

Now whenever any date reconcilations need to be done we have a lot of methods and properties to achieve it. Now in the current scenario, if you want to get date i.e. 30 days prior to the date. Here is the logic.

```
var priorDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-30);
```

Now in addition to this, if Date needs to be formatted, here are the various ways it can be formatted.
[Date Formats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mNCL.png)